# Fear of teaching my child academics on my own

Tags: pre-schooler, primary-schooler

I have a 4yo and a 6yo. I want to enrich them in academics (reading, math etc) in weekends. They like when we do it. I do have one fear - maybe I'm teaching them "wrong"? I mean I know the material for sure, and we have books, but to actually teach correctly one needs to know how to approach the material, how to not to teach them into repeating common errors, how to teach them to work independently and not help them too much... I'm thinking I might end up doing more harm than good and it is better let accredited teachers do the work. Is there any base for this fear?

Comment: "If you can't do, teach. If you can't teach then teach the teachers. If you can't teach the teachers then become an inspector". So, using maths, for example, is one level, but being able to explain things needs a deeper level of understanding. Do you have that?

Answer (score 8):

Don't think of your enriching as proper teaching. Do fun stuff, bake a cake (maths - measuring weights and volumes, english - reading the recipe, bonus - cake) go to a museum or art gallery, go to the library and borrow books and cuddle up and read them together. Go shopping, have them write/read the shopping list, count the correct numbers of things, calculate which is better value, add up the total etc. If they ask "why?" and, lets face it children often do, and you don't know the answer then say so and see if you can work it out together. Build lego. Ask questions about the world, even if you don't know. All this is just embedding what they should be learning at school, but not sitting down and "teaching", they get enough of that in the week.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Kids who have school all day don't want to have more school on weekends. But learning should be different than just studying subjects at school; it should be fun for the kids, exposing kids to different interests and ideally create curious kids with the skills to explore whatever stirs their imaginations.